# how to escape/ properly print text containing quotes & brackets in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding a filed to a woocommerce shortcode button named 'onclick'. This is needed to track click events in Google Analytics.

This is how the code button short code looks after adding the onclick attribute:

```
function woo_shortcode_button( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'size' => '',
                                    'style' => '',
                                    'bg_color' => '',
                                    'color' => '',
                                    'border' => '',
                                    'text' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'link' => '#',
                                    'window' => '',
                                    'onclick' => '' ), $atts ) );


    // Set custom background and border color
    $color_output = '';
    if ( $color ) {
        $preset_colors = array( 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'aqua', 'teal', 'purple', 'pink', 'silver' );
        if ( in_array( $color, $preset_colors ) ) {
            $class .= ' ' . $color;
        } else {
            if ( $border ){
                $border_out = $border;
            } else {
                $border_out = $color;
            }

            $color_output = 'style="background:' . esc_attr( $color ) . ';border-color:' . esc_attr( $border_out ) . '"';

            // add custom class
            $class .= ' custom';
        }
    } else {
        if ( $border )
                $border_out = $border;
            else
                $border_out = $bg_color;

            $color_output = 'style="background:' . esc_attr( $bg_color ) . ';border-color:' . esc_attr( $border_out ) . '"';

            // add custom class
            $class .= ' custom';
    }

    $class_output = '';

    // Set text color
    if ( $text ) $class_output .= ' dark';
    // Set class
    if ( $class ) $class_output .= ' '.$class;
    // Set Size
    if ( $size ) $class_output .= ' '.$size;
    // Set window target
    if ( $window ) $window = 'target="_blank" ';
    // Set onclick
    if ( $onclick ) $onclick = 'onclick="'. $onclick .'" ';

    $output = '<a ' . $window . esc_attr($onclick) . 'href="' . esc_attr( esc_url( $link ) ) . '" class="woo-sc-button' . esc_attr( $class_output ) . '" ' . $color_output . '><span class="woo-' . esc_attr( $style ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( woo_remove_wpautop( $content ) ) . '</span></a>';
    return $output;
} // End woo_shortcode_button()

add_shortcode( 'button', 'woo_shortcode_button' );
```

Google Analytic's click event text looks like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'trackthis', 'Click', 'home-a']);
```

So a complete button short code example would be:

```
[button window="yes" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'trackthis', 'Click', 'home-a']);"]hi[/button]
```

But when I publish it the code is broken and looks like:

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="&quot;”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’,&quot;" href="#" class="woo-sc-button  custom" style="background:;border-color:"><span class="woo-">);”]hi</span></a>
```

How do I properly output this text?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to implement the suggestions to remove the function using the below two changes:

```
if ( $onclick ) $onclick = 'onclick="'. esc_attr($onclick) .'" ';

$output = '<a ' . $window . $onclick . 'href="' . esc_attr( esc_url( $link ) ) . '" class="woo-sc-button' . esc_attr( $class_output ) . '" ' . $color_output . '><span class="woo-' . esc_attr( $style ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( woo_remove_wpautop( $content ) ) . '</span></a>';
```

I get:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="woo-sc-button  custom" style="background:;border-color:"><span class="woo-">);"]hi</span></a>
```

**Update 2**:

Took suggestion to remove the encoding all together and add a space between the `$window` and `$onclick` variables:

```
if ( $onclick ) $onclick = 'onclick="'. $onclick .'" ';

$output = '<a ' . $window . ' ' . $onclick . 'href="' . esc_attr( esc_url( $link ) ) . '" class="woo-sc-button' . esc_attr( $class_output ) . '" ' . $color_output . '><span class="woo-' . esc_attr( $style ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( woo_remove_wpautop( $content ) ) . '</span></a>';
```

The output looks the same:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="woo-sc-button  custom" style="background:;border-color:"><span class="woo-">);"]hi</span></a>
```

And just to clarify further, when the input doesn't include any special string the output is fine:

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="dosomething" href="#" class="woo-sc-button  custom" style="background:;border-color:"><span class="woo-">hi</span></a>
```

Comment: Your logic here seems wrong, you are escaping to late and double escaping. Also, you should not use `extract()`. This function was dropped from core more than a year ago. Look at the shortcode api how to write a proper shortcode

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm editing a code from a previous coder. I get that I double escape but now even tough I'm not it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you simply `var_dump($onclick)`? Does it actually contain data?

Comment: @rnevius see the example in the bottom of my question. When I add a simple string it outputs correctly.

Comment: That's not what I asked. When you add the analytics string, and `var_dump($onclick)`, what is the output?

Comment: Your problem is in this piece of code `' . wp_kses_post( wpautop( $content ) ) . '`

Comment: @PieterGoosen...how do you figure? That is only applied to the content within the link, not the `onclick` attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is twofold.

1. You are using square brackets in your attributes. WP sees this as a closing tag for your shortcode (it's not recommended to use quotes in your attribute values but it's possible).
2. Don't use spaces in your attributes, it messes things up.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes

You could do something like this.

### Find bracket and replace it with square bracket + bracket

Shortcode (got rid of spaces and square brackets):

```
[button window="yes" onclick="_gaq.push('_trackEvent','trackthis','Click','home-a');"]hi[/button]
```

Shortcode function (find bracket and replace it with square bracket + bracket):

```
if ( $onclick ) $onclick = 'onclick="'. $onclick .'" ';

$onclick = str_replace("(", "([", $onclick);
$onclick = str_replace(")", "])", $onclick);

$output = '<a ' . $window . $onclick . 'href="' . esc_attr( esc_url( $link ) ) . '" class="woo-sc-button' . esc_attr( $class_output ) . '" ' . $color_output . '><span class="woo-' . esc_attr( $style ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $content  ) . '</span></a>';
```

### Or you could put the gaqpush from the argument in to the shortcode.

Shortcode:

```
[button window="yes" onclick="'_trackEvent','trackthis','Click','home-a'"]hi[/button]
```

Function:

```
if ( $onclick ) $onclick = "onclick='_gaq.push([". $onclick ."']); ";
```

Comment: thanks! just change the quotes location in the end of the answer

Comment: You're welcome! I just changed quote locations in final answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr), [esc_attr()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr):

> Encodes the <, >, &, " and ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote and single quote) characters.

To solve the issue, you simply need to remove that function:

```
$output = '<a ' . $window . ' ' . $onclick . 'href="' . esc_attr( esc_url( $link ) ) . '" class="woo-sc-button' . esc_attr( $class_output ) . '" ' . $color_output . '><span class="woo-' . esc_attr( $style ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( woo_remove_wpautop( $content ) ) . '</span></a>';
```

Comment: Tried it.. doesn't work see the update in my question

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. Also, you don't want to encode the your quotes, so you **shouldn't** be using `esc_attr()` (as mentioned in the other answer) at all.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape attribute value, not it's name and quotes around a value as you ruining quotes around value. See how href, class and style done.
So you should use

```
if ( $onclick ) $onclick = 'onclick="'. esc_attr($onclick) .'" ';
```

but use just $onclick when building output as @rnevius written.

Comment: @Tom I made simplified example locally and that working for me. Did you forget to actually set 'onclick' function parameter when calling it?

Comment: @SeriousDron what do you mean by that? There is an input to the attribute see the button shortcode: '[button window="yes" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'trackthis', 'Click', 'home-a']);"]hi[/button] ' Maybe you haven't used this specific string?

Comment: @rnevis Yes, it will. But it's ok. Browser will parse it correctly. Try it here http://seriousdron.ru/1.php

Comment: @SeriousDron This isn't under the WordPress/Woocommerce platform. Something happens in between.

Comment: @rnevis It's not. It's just string where single quotes are escaped to show that it's ok.

Comment: @rnevius That's exactly my point. WordPress is doing something in between that's why it's not a valid example.